# Induction help strong induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I need some help with the induction step. I got to $2a(k) + a(k-1)$ but don't know how to continue. Any solution/help?

> Define the function $a(n)$ as follows:
>   $$a(n)=\begin{cases}
> 5&n=1\\
> 10&n=2\\
> 2a(n-1)+a(n-2)&n\ge3\end{cases}$$
>   and let $S(n)$ represent $a(n)\lt3^n$. Use either *simple* or *strong* induction to prove that $S(n)$ is true for all $n\ge3,\,n\in\mathbb{N}$. (**Hint**: It is much easier to prove $S(n)$ if you choose the right form of induction!)

What I've done so far:
Base cases $n = 3, 4, 5$

$n=3$
$a(3) = 2*a(2) + a(1) = 25$
$25<3^3 \Rightarrow 25<27 \implies S(n)$ holds

$n=4$
$a(4) = 2*a(3) + a(2) = 64$
$64<3^4 \Rightarrow 64<81 \implies S(n)$ holds

$n=5$
$a(5) = 2*a(4) + a(3) = 189 <3^5 \implies S(n)$ holds

Induction hypothesis:
Assume $S(k)$ holds, then $S(k) < 3^k$
$2*a(k-1) + a(k-2) < 3^k$

Induction Step:
Prove $S(k) \implies S(k+1)$
$2*a(k) + a(k-1) < 3^k+1$

I'm confused from here on.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the work you did? It is unclear what you've done so far if you just say you got to $2a(k)+a(k-1)$.

Comment: done. Could you show me now what to do next?

Comment: What happens when you say that $3^{\{k+1\}} = 3^k * 3$? Separate that out and play with the inequalities.

Comment: but the 2 infront of 3^k on the left side messes it up. I have 2*3^k + 3^k-1 < 3^k * 3. If i manipulate this i cant seperate the 2.

Comment: You're not trying to get rid of the $2$. All we are doing is writing everything out in a different form so we can see if there is any way that it relates to your inductive hypothesis. That is the key here.

Comment: i got 1/3 (3^k +3^k/3) <3^k. Im getting really confused. Could you show me how to do what youre saying?

Comment: Let me solve this really quick and I'll give you some hints.

Comment: 1: Fix the way you write your hypothesis. Write everything without using $S(n)$ in your inequality. You'll see everything more clearly.

2: You are trying to show that $a(k) < 3^k$ implies that $a(k+1) < 3^{k+1}$

3: $a(k) = a(3k-4)$ and $a(k+1) = a(3k-1)$ when you expand both expressions out.

4: You know that $a(k) = a(3k-4) < 3^k$. What can you say about  $a(k+1) = a(3k-1)$ in relation to $3^{k+1} = 3^{k} * 3$?

Comment: One more hint: $a(k+1) = a(3k-1) = a(3k-4) + 3a$ What does this look like?

Comment: You should arrive at something that looks like this $...<3^k + 3a < ...< 3^{k+1}$. And that will prove your statement.

Comment: [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a really helpful guide to MathJax formatting :)

Comment: Even your calculation of $a(4)$ is wrong, because $2\cdot a(3)+a(2)=2\cdot25+10=60$, not 64.

Answer (score 1):

You need something along these lines:

Assume that for all $k\le n,  a(k) < 3^k$

Show that $a(n+1) < 3^{n+1}$

$a(n+1) = 2a(n) + a(n-1) < 2\cdot 3^n + 3^{n-1} = 7\cdot 3^{n-1} < 3^{n+1}$

Comment: 7? Where did you get a 7 from lol.Should it be 6 ?

Comment: $2\cdot 3^n + 3^{n-1} = (2\cdot 3 + 1)3^{n-1}$

Comment: Sorry for the continuous questions, but how does 7/3*(3^n-1) prove its <3^n?

Comment: $7\cdot 3^{n-1} < 9\cdot 3^{n-1} = 3^{n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your proof:

Your base cases should be $1$ and $2$, rather than $3$, $4$, and $5$

But even more importantly, you should have paid more attention to the provided Hint:

> (**Hint**: It is much easier to prove $S(n)$ if you choose the right form of induction!)

You tried to use weak induction, where you try to show $S(n) \Rightarrow S(n+1)$

But, given the recursive definition of $a(n)$, which shows that $a(n)$ is a function of $a(n-1)$ *and* $a(n-2)$, you want to use a stronger version of induction: one where you assume $S(n-2)$ and $S(n-1)$ in order to show $S(n)$.

For this, you can either use *strong* induction: $\forall k \le n \ S(k) \Rightarrow S(n+1)$

or just a custom form of what is called *strong weak induction*: Prove at least two base cases, and then prove that for any $n \ge 3$: $(S(n-2) \land S(n-1)) \Rightarrow S(n)$

I'll use the latter.

Now, as I said earlier, your bases cases should be $1$ and $2$, rather than $3$, $4$, and $5$.

So:

Case $n=1$: $a(1) = 5 > 3 = 3^1$ Check!

Case $n=2$: $a(2) = 10 > 9 = 3^2$ Check!

OK, now let's do the step: let's assume $n \ge 3$, and let's assume $S(n-2)$ and $S(n-1)$

Then:

$$a(n) = 2 \cdot a(n-1) + a(n-2) < \text{ (By Inductive Hypothesis)}$$

$$2\cdot 3^{n-1} + 3^{n-2} < 2\cdot 3^{n-1} + 3\cdot 3^{n-2} = 2\cdot 3^{n-1} + 3^{n-1} = 3^n$$

Check!